# copy a txt file from Unix machine to Windows machine

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below shell script to copy a txt file from a Unix machine to a Windows machine in the same network:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='localhost'
USER='redacted'
PASSWD='redacted'
FILE='/los_prod/scripts/log.txt'

ftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER
$PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

It's giving the error as:

> :connection failed.

I am giving all the correct info in the script. What could be the reason?

Comment: part of this perl script might help you as you have a problem in logging in: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/ftp-using-perl-and-getting-files-based.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look here:
http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html

It gives a simple way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`ftp` doesn't accept input from `stdin`, so you can't just feed the login information in like that.  You'd need to use a program like [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to automate the normal `ftp` command-line client.  A better alternative may be to use another language instead of a Bourne shell script.  Something like Perl (as mentioned by @sarathi), Ruby, or Python would allow you to write a fairly small script and use the FTP libraries available to them to more easily script it.

Here's a version of your script for `expect`:

```
set host "localhost"
set user "redacted"
set pass "redacted"
set file "/los_prod/scripts/log.txt"

spawn ftp $host
expect "Name"
send "$user\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\n"
expect "ftp>"
send "put $file\n"
expect "ftp>"
send "quit\n"
```

You'll probably have to install `expect` on your system; it's not as widely available as other interpreters.  Any modern Linux distro will have a package for it.